# Плохо работает корневой домен .local

Tags: ip, dns, localhost, domain, локальная-сеть

На одном из компьютеров запущен простой web-сервер, с сертификатом SSL который подписан CA, сертификат CA установлен на всех машинах в локальной сети. При переходе на ПК на котором запущен сервер по ссылке (имя_пк.local) все работает хорошо, но на других компьютерах в сети сайт очень долго загружается, как и ресурсы сайта. Но если на этих компьютерах вводить IP-адрес как (192.168.0.ххх), то всё загружается очень быстро. Использовать IP-адрес не хотелось бы, так как он меняется, и прописывать все варианты в сертификате не хочется. Hosts файл редактировать тоже не вариант. В чем может быть проблема? Как ускорить загрузку или что сделать?

Comment: А откуда другие ПК узнают, какому IP-адресу соответствует домен имя_пк.local? Из текущего описания складывается впечатление, что это вообще чудо, что это хоть как-то работает

Comment: Web-Server у вас не Denwer случайно?

Comment: @andreymal На ПК с запущенным сервером включено обнаружение в сети, "имя_пк" соответствует имени ПК в сети. Возможно это работает через mDNS. Насколько я знаю у других этот метод работает, но меня смутила его скорость. Попробуйте прочитать о ".local" [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304058/how-to-view-localhost-on-my-ipod-touch/9304094#9304094] Вдохновился этим вопросом, судя по ответам это возможно и всё работает)

Comment: @Alexey Нет, простой скрипт сервера на Python